# How to run from JavaScript console in Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a WEB page thats requires to run `fw3k2_request_job_application()` from JavaScript console in Google Chrome to get some URL with some data.
How can i do it?

Request is:

> Run fw3k2_request_job_application() from your JavaScript console so you can acces link with data

Answer (score 0):

Press `F12`, then select `Console` tab and paste the code to execute.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Feel free to accept the answer if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Press ctrl-shift-I (or from the menu choose "More tools / Developer tools") to bring up the developer tools, and  you'll see the console tab